# Android WebView JS - Start audio automatically on load with custom function

Tags: javascript, html, audio

I got a custom JS function for the audio tag. It does also handle the progress bar. When I click on the related tag `<a onclick="playSound(1)">` it works.
But when I want to start it on page load this function does not work anymore.
I thought it could be a reason about EventListeners - but with my logic I only add an event to the timeline (progress bar). I got no idea why it does not trigger the audio file!

Here my function:

```
    //Play and Pause
function playSound(id) {
    var param1 = "play" + id;
    var param2 = "audioFile" + id;
    var param3 = "timeline"+id;
    var param4 = "playhead"+id;
    var param5 = "timeNumbers"+id;

    var playBtn = document.getElementById(param1);
    var audioFile = document.getElementById(param2);
    var timeline = document.getElementById(param3);
    var playhead = document.getElementById(param4);
    var progressTime = document.getElementById(param5);

    // start music
    if (audioFile.paused) {
        audioFile.play();
        // remove play, add pause
        playBtn.innerHTML = '<img src="img/pause.svg" />';
        playBtn.className = "paused";
    } else { // pause music
        audioFile.pause();
        // remove pause, add play
        playBtn.innerHTML = '<img src="img/play.svg" />';
        playBtn.className = "playBtn";
    }

    //handle timeline
    var duration = audioFile.duration;
    var timelineWidth = timeline.offsetWidth - playhead.offsetWidth;

    audioFile.addEventListener("timeupdate", timeUpdate, false);
    // makes timeline clickable
    timeline.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
        moveplayhead(event);
        audioFile.currentTime = duration * clickPercent(event);
    }, false);

    function clickPercent(event) {
        return (event.clientX - getPosition(timeline)) / timelineWidth;
    }

    function moveplayhead(event) {
        var newMargLeft = event.clientX - getPosition(timeline);

        if (newMargLeft >= 0 && newMargLeft <= timelineWidth) {
            playhead.style.marginLeft = newMargLeft + "px";
        }
        if (newMargLeft < 0) {
            playhead.style.marginLeft = "0px";
        }
        if (newMargLeft > timelineWidth) {
            playhead.style.marginLeft = timelineWidth + "px";
        }
    }
```

As i mentioned above when i call the `<a onclick"playSound(2)">` it works great.
But when i do in my external JS just `playSound(2).` it does not start. 
Please no suggestions with "Why not start with the html attribute autoplay"
or any JQuery solutions - just JS please.

UPDATE:

Since it is used in an Android WebView i found the information:
Autoplay on most mobile platforms (Android, iOS) gets blocked to avoid poor user experiences.

**Solution**

```
webSettings.setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture(false);
```

did the magic :)

Comment: Is `playSound(2)` call within handler of `window` `load` event?

Comment: please post your html

Comment: I tried the onload - no success - but the function is executed - I can see it since the play button change his state. @Rachel I got currently no simple fiddle since it is a big project with dependencies.

Comment: @TobiasAlt  minimal and verifiable example is required to reproduce the issue. Just post the relevant excerpt

Comment: The audio source is loaded via url - maybe it is not ready?? Or a lifecycle problem ? but window.onload evaluate this - I thougt.

Comment: It is not necessary to reproduce the entire project, only portion which is not producing expected result. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to ensure all DOM content is loaded before you initiate the `playsound()` function.  Something like the following will solve this...

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    playsound(2);
}, false);
```

See [DOMContentLoaded @ MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded).

Comment: @TobiasAlt : unless the new eventListener is beyond the Scope of the playsound function then I'm officially at a loss.

Comment: Please do not down vote me - but I forget to say I use this in an Android WebView and now found this -> Autoplay on most mobile platforms (Android, iOS) gets blocked to avoid poor user experiences. Thank you  for your help all and sry forget to say it its a webview. I have to do a workaround now.

Comment: @TobiasAlt They don't like to make things too easy - keeps us on our toes.  Good luck!

Comment: That`s true Brian. Thanks and Good Evening.

Comment: If you ever get into this case I found the solution and updated it in my question.